# asp.net MVC 4 FilePathResult error: "The directory property cannot be found in the cache"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, io, download

In my asp.net MVC 4 application, I have an action that returns FilePathResult.

In my local machine and QA server this action worked with no error.

In the production server it is throwing exception: "The directory property cannot be found in the cache"

This is the code I have:

```
public FileResult Export(string type,string tableName)
    {
        var outputFileName = IOHelper.BuildOutputFileNameAndPath("output.csv", tableName)
        tableAPI.ExportTables(type, outputFileName);

        return File(outputFileName, "text/csv", type + ".csv");

    }
```

The difference between the QA server and production server is that the application files in the production server is on a NETWORK DRIVE and not local drive.

The value of the outputFileName variable is File Path is: \\[the root directory of the app]\App_Data\AdminTablesBackup\output.csv

I can see that the file is created but it fails when trying to return the file to the client.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the account you are running your Application Pool under has sufficient read permissions to this shared folder. If you are running under the default ApplicationPoolIdentity chances are that this account will not have permissions to access network shares.

Comment: Worked like a charm :-)